# Dynamics CRM 2011 shows unsaved data pop-up on close when no data has changed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

On our Dynamics CRM 2001 website, I have a weird problem. When I open a record and then close it without modifying anything, I get the pop-up that says I have unsaved changes, even though nothing was changed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the pop-up is shown when a field is marked as "dirty", in other words when its value displayed on the form is not equal to the value as its was retrieved. Sometimes this problem is just a simple matter of the form display trimming the spaces in a lookup field. Say for example that a lookup field is named "Test  " (note the spaces). Upon display in the form, this value sometimes gets trimmed to "Test", which causes the values to be different and thus marked as dirty. The same problem can occur with newlines.

Luckily, it is quite easy to find out which fields are marked as dirty. First, go to the form's definition page. There, open the form properties page where you'll find the JavaScript libraries being loaded. Create a new library with the following contents:

`function find_dirty_fields_on_save() {
    console.log(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml());
}`

Then select the `OnSave` event and add an event handler to our newly added `find_dirty_fields_on_save()` function.

Now save the form and publish it.

The final step is to go to a record that had the pop-up problem. Open the record's page and open a developer console that will allow you to view the output of `console.log` commands. Do nothing on the record page and click on the save button. At this point, our custom function is called which will log (as XML) the fields that will be saved. As only dirty fields are saved, you can now find them in your developer console.

Comment: if you get that popup can be for two reason: 1) you have some javascript inside onload event that makes the form dirty 2) you are in a rollup with a bug that cause the form to be dirty when it's not, I saw something similar with a CRM 2011 RTM instance

Comment: It was indeed a bug with the rollup, as I found the field considered dirty through  `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml()` was not actually modified at all.